# Как определить какой узел был выбран при правом клике мышки по узлу дерева?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate...
    <StackPanel>                                    
    <TextBlock  >
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >      
                <MenuItem   MouseRightButtonDown="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem">
```

Answer (score 0):

Это событие возвращает object sender и MouseButtonEventArgs e. Через e.Source можно определить что вызвало событие:

```
        TreeViewItem source = (TreeViewItem)e.Source;
        string name = source.Header.ToString();
```